# How to tell the search engine to fill in the blanks?

Tags: search-engines, title, search-terms

Google has an awesome feature to allow you to search for search terms where you don't know one or more words but [Google guesses it for you](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en):

> Fill in the blank (*)
>
> Add an asterisk within a search as a placeholder for any unknown or wildcard terms. Use with quotation marks to find variations of that exact phrase or to remember words in the middle of a phrase.
>
> ie. "a * saved is a * earned"

I'm trying to tweak a title so it does the contrary. If people searchs for:

> a tree saved is a air earned;
> a sea saved is a fish earned

It will show my result as if they were searching for *"a * saved is a * earned"*. Is there a way to get this behavior?

Comment: Yes. With a page for every possible word. Each page must perform far better than any page with the word penny. And by the way, you have to have content for each page. Sound silly? You cannot game Google'a Ajax very easily especially as you described. It can be manipulated to recognize you brand- never mind how- and other specific terms and phrases. But it cannot be realistically manipulated as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rank for a phrase in Google you generally have to **use the words from the phrase** on your page. So if somebody were searching for "a tree saved is a air earned", then to rank for that phrase, you should use the phrase on the page, ideally in the title.

There are a few exceptions to this:

- Google will substitute misspellings.  If somebody searches for "a tre saved is a air earned", Google will likely still recommend your page the ranks for the correct spelling.
- Google will substitute synonyms.  Your page may still rank for "a tree preserved is a  air earned".
- Google often ignore unimportant words in a query so when somebody asks "What is a tree saved is an air earned?" Google will find the page that has just "tree saved air earned" on it.

Google puts a lot of emphasis on returning relevant results.  They do not consider it a good user experience to show one page to a large variety of search terms that contain important terms not on the page.

Comment: So, for google ranking is the same in the title "a tree saved is a air earned" and "a saved is a earned"?

Comment: Google will usually only show the page for queries with "tree" in them if "tree" is used on the page.   The page is more likely to rank for a phrase if the words from the phrase are used in the title.